# MSBUILD Publish Web Application Copying References to Wrong Path

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-applications, msbuild, publishing

I am trying to use MSBUILD to build and then publish a web application to a folder.

I can build the code fine but then when it comes to publishing the application I can't seem to get that to work properly.

I have the following Target to publish the application:

```
<Target Name="Publish">
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(OutputFolder)" ContinueOnError="true" />
    <MSBuild Projects="WebApp.Web.csproj"
         Targets="ResolveReferences;_CopyWebApplication"
         Properties="WebProjectOutputDir=$(OutputFolder);OutDir=$(WebProjectOutputDir)\" 
    />
</Target>
```

I currently have the output folder to be:

```
 <OutputFolder>C:\TestOutput\Test</OutputFolder>
```

Everything gets placed in here nicely except for the references from other projects which get placed just on the C:\ drive in no folder. I can't seem to mess with anything to change them to get in the bin folder.

Answer (score -1):

You should probably add a few more properties like `PublishDir` And `PublishUrl`

Here is what I use to publish from `MSBuild`

```
<MSBuild Projects="$(PublishProjectName)\$(PublishProjectName).csproj" Targets="Publish"   Properties="PublishDir=$(PublishDirectory)\;PublishUrl=$(PublishDirectory)\;Configuration=$(Configuration)$(BuildFramework);BuildConstants=$(BuildConstants);MSBuildTargets=$(BuildTargets)" />
```